# Hosting error of ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net

I registered with a free service to test my ASP.Net application.  I just made a basic application to test how it works over the internet.  The hosting service sent me following email

> Your user name is: kfsehgal
>   Your password is: psswrdwd
>   Your URL to access your site is: http://users8.Jabry.com/kfsehgal
>   FTP Host is: ftp8.Jabry.com
>   You can begin transferring your web pages to our server using any standerd FTP Client such as CuteFTP and WS_FTP.
>   Also, you can use our Web-based File Manager.

I went to publish and tried both http://users8.jarby.com/kfsehgal and 
ftp8.jarby.com but little later after Publish starts, it says publish failed, without giving any more reasons.
Please help if I am doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

The 'output' window in Visual Studio should explain to you why publish failed.

You can also look at the target site on FTP to see what actually got copied over.

I've had instances where Visual Studio would tell me publish failed because it couldn't send a JavaScript file to the target server, but everything else was copied fine. When that happens, publish didn't actually fail in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

This site is fake!

I´ve signed up but can´t login, found some reports that people can't login.

Probably a valid email hunter.